# Equation of a straight line passing through two points and distance point straight - C

Tags: line, distance, point

I have 3 points, `p1(x1,y1)`, `p2(x2,y2)` and `p3(x3,y3)`.

I know that the equation of the straight line passing throught `p1` and `p2` should be obtained from `(x-x1)/(x2-x1)=(y-y1)/(y2-y1)`, but how can I put it inside a variable?

And after that, how can I calculate the distance from `p3` to this line?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Would you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/43327070/edit) to add code?

Comment: This is basic vector math, not a programming questions.

Comment: What do you mean by " how can I put it inside a variable"?

Comment: Variables, in C, cannot hold "functions". I suspect if you can reword your question differently you may come up with the answers on your own.

Comment: @KOUSIKMANDAL If I use that formula, in which type of variable should I store the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all transform your line equation to another form

`Ax + By + C = 0` // keep int mind that `A^2 + B^2 != 0` (this means that A or B are unable to be equall to zero in one moment)

it will be `(y1- y2)x + (x2 - x1)y + (x1y2 - x2y1) = 0;`

if you have an equation of a line `Ax + By + C = 0`

the distance form point `M(Mx, My)` to your line will be

```
d = abs(A * Mx + B * My + C)/sqrt(A * A + B * B)
```

you're welcome

Answer (score 1):

A line can be represented by a tuple of 3 numbers `a`, `b` and `c` using the form `ax + by = c` (or using the slope-intercept form too). So what you can do is to create a class named `Line` that stores 3 public members of `int` or `float` type.

You can then implement a distance function within your class using the [standard point-line distance formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line).

In C#, you could do something like:

```
class Line
{
  public float a,b,c;

  public float Distance(Point p)
  {
    return Math.Abs(a * p.X + b * p.Y + c)/Math.Sqrt(a * a + b * b)
  }
}
```

C version should be pretty much the same.

Answer (score 1):

The following code computes distance between two points.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    double p1x,p1y,p2x,p2y,p1p2_distance;
    //Initialize variables here

    // Distance d between p1 and p2 is given by: d = sqrt((p2.x-p1.x)^2 + (p2.y-
    p1.y)^2)
    p1p2_distance = sqrt(pow((p2x-p1x),2)+pow((p2y-p1y),2)); // same formula can be used to calculate distance between p1,p3 and p2,p3.

    printf("Distance between p1 and p2: %f \n", &p1p2_distance);
    return 0;
}
```

On Linux compile with: gcc distance.c -o distance -lm